# 9 errors, line o.o (can't figure out how to fix)

Tags: c#

I'm getting 9 errors on 1 line, and I cannot figure out how to fix the errors. I've tried & failed, so, I'm going to ask you all if you know whats wrong:

code:

```
string file = Path.Combine(arg1, filenam); //This is the line that defines "file"
var Wfile = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(file FileMode.Open));
```

Errors:
No overload for method 'Open' takes 1 arguments

Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

) expected

Invalid expression term ')'

; expected

Invalid expression term ')'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a comma:

```
var Wfile = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(file, FileMode.Open));
```

You have to separate arguments to a method with a comma. As you can see in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.open%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), specifying a `FileMode` requires you to have 2 arguments. Fairly sure all your errors are caused because of the resulting syntax errors.

Comment: Hahhah, those syntax  errors. Always get me :p

Comment: In such situations it's important to carefully read the error message: `No overload for method 'Open' takes 1 arguments` should raise flags as to why the compiler thinks you're only having one argument!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing a comma. The following...

```
var Wfile = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(file FileMode.Open));
```

should be...

```
var Wfile = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(file, FileMode.Open));
```

Good Luck!